# Problema con controlador JSF, Spring e Hibernate

Tags: jsf, spring, hibernate

Estoy desarrollando con JSF, Spring and hibernate y no puedo crear un Controller con mis métodos propios para poder llamarlos desde el xhtml, este es mi codigo

HomeController.java

```
@ManagedBean
public class HomeController implements Serializable{

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String descripcion;
    public HomeController() {
        this.descripcion = "OK";
    }
    public String getDescripcion() {
        return this.descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }
    public void UserLog(){
        log.info("somethings");
    }
}
```

home.xhtml

```
<h:commandButton value="#{HomeController.descripcion}" action="#    {HomeController.UserLog()}"/>
```

Pero no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Salvo que se especifique explícitamente, los nombres asignados a los managed beans en el scope son el nombre de la clase empezando en minúscula. Así, tu bean HomeController sería accesible a través de homeController, y tu código quedaría:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{homeController.descripcion}" action="#{homeController.UserLog()}"/>
```

Comment: Cuidado. El método del action debería ser `action="#{homeController.userLog}"`